# How does Digg retrieves password from facebook? (at Facebook Connect)

Tags: facebook, passwords, digg

When I logged into Digg using my Facebook account, Digg asked me to create its own account.
I agreed and entered a username only(!). And after that I have the possibility to login into the Digg without Facebook Connect.

So the question is - How does Digg know my password?

Comment: It shouldn't go on super-user because the question is about a website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't. It uses [**OAuth**](http://oauth.net/).

Comment: but what will be with my Digg account if i will disconnect from facebook? How i will log in?